# masonry imagesLoaded, $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked through similar problems like I have on here, but still couldn't figure out my problem.
I have several images on a website, that I want to be ordered in a masonry style. However, sometimes they get stacked on top of each other, so I tried to add imagesLoaded function, but I get the error: $(...).imagesLoaded is not a function.

here are my linked scripts in html code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.5/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mymasonry.js"></script>
```

here are the images I want to be displayed:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row centered mt mb">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery post">
                <img src="images/a1.jpg" class="img-responsive">Size:  x <br> Title: </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery post">
                <img src="images/a2.jpg" class="img-responsive">Size:  x <br> Title: </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery post">
                <img src="images/a3.jpg" class="img-responsive">Size:  x <br> Title: </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery post">
                <img src="images/a4.jpg" class="img-responsive">Size:  x <br> Title:</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery post">
                <img src="images/a5.jpg" class="img-responsive">Size:  x <br> Title:</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and here is my javascript code for masonry and imagesLoaded that I want to use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.container').imagesLoaded(function(){

$(function(){

    var m = new Masonry($('.centered').get()[0], {
        itemSelector: ".post"
    });

})
})
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I am linking the imagesLoaded javascript. Why am I getting the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the core masonry library. Also I would suggest moving all of your scripts to just above the end body tag. Right now you have an old version of jquery and a bootstrap.js script sitting down there. I have refactored your script dependencies below. Cut and paste those and replace the two scripts you have at the bottom of your page and then remove the scripts from your head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mymasonry.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you replace your mymasonry.js with this version: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js

Comment: I tried, still didn't help.
the website is: http://www.donnaliartist.com/index.php if you want to check.

Comment: I'll take a look at your site but my fiddle worked with your above code and my suggestions.

Comment: Okay I see what you have done now... I did not know what the mymasonry.js file was. I assumed you had downloaded a version of masonry and saved it to your local. I'm going to create a fresh answer below and help you out with some of your script placements as well.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't worked with masonry before (this is the first time I'm trying to apply it) and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127221/discussion-between-adrianopolis-and-user1902427).

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to declare the function outside the (document).ready that is fired on load. The way it currently it is, you are passing in your function (loader code) into a callback for a function that has not been declared yet.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.container').imagesLoaded()
});

var imagesLoaded = function()
{    
    var m = new Masonry($('.centered').get()[0], {
        itemSelector: ".post"
    });    
}
```

Comment: I replaced my code for this, but I still get the same error. 
http://www.donnaliartist.com/index.php